VSCode extension development: Referencing a script file in vscode extension webview
I am successfully able to reference scripts in a webview using the approach mentioned in vscode documentation during extension development, but when it gets bundled, the pathing no longer works.
So, for example, my whole source code sits within a src directory, and so to reference a script in a webview, I do:
const cssPathOnDisk = vscode.Uri.joinPath(
    context.extensionUri,
    'src',
    'modules',
    'main',
    'styles.css'
  );
  const styleUri = panel.webview.asWebviewUri(cssPathOnDisk);

But when I run vsce package, the styles.css doesn't get bundled - and also, it is still trying to reference 'src', but vscode's bundle directory is 'out'.
What do I need to do to fix this? Do these sorts of files need to be in a specific directory?

I think you should check out content-security-policy
or add toString() method after asWebviewUri() so let styleUri => styleUrl
const styleUrl = panel.webview.asWebviewUri(cssPathOnDisk).toString();

